# configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element(line 78)

Tags: openvpn

I have installed OpenVPN and I have downloaded the `.ovpn` file, but I am unable to import the file in *Network Settings* → *VPN* → *Import file* option.
Result:

```
Cannot import VPN connection
The filen vpn.ovpn could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information
Error: configuration error: unsupported blob/xml element(line 78)
```

Any solution?

Comment: Well, what's on line 78 of the conf file?

Comment: 78 -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 4):

In my case, my ovpn file has the xml element `<connection>` `</connection>`, which is not supported by `nmcli`. Thus I remove `<connection>` `</connection>`, and it works

`sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file myvpn.conf`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

This Bug is around since ages in Ubuntu - See here:
 [this bug on Launchpad here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365)

The key to success is to strip out your inline certificates/keys into separate files, import the ovpn file and set the certificates manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use OpenVPN on XFCE/Xubuntu, you have to install the according "network-manager" tool first. Use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

and/or see [here](https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/NetworkManager/#VPN).